# Is it possible to stream voice to directline API from native app on iOS using Swift or Objective-c

Tags: ios, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have a bot that leverages all the cool tech that comes with botframework, e.g. LUIS, QnA maker, adaptivecards, etc.  The bot works well and I can use WebChat to connect to and ask questions and get responses.  However, I now need native iOS (and eventually Android) app that can perform much like webchat does but I do not want to embed webchat in a web control in native app.  I plan to have voice always on leveraging something like snowboy or picovoice for hotword to wake app and send commands to bot - users would ask things like "hey bot what is weather in Boston" and get presented with result message or adaptivecard.

Is voice steaming to directline API from Swift on iOS possible (I know most things are possible so any pointers would be greatly appreciated)?  Or am I approaching from wrong angle and perhaps there is better/easier way to achieve my goal?

Comment: This is outside of the scope of what our support team handles, but you may want to look into [DirectLine Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). If your app implements it, I believe it may accomplish what you need.

Comment: Yes I have thanks @mdrichardson-MSFT - every time I think I have it figured out I seem to run into a new blocker.  Now delving into [Speech SDK for Objective-C Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/objectivec/cognitive-services/speech/) but suspect will need to reach out to someone on LUIS team to see if they can help me.